# what is the counter part of boost::date_time::not_a_date_time in STL

Tags: c++, boost, stl

Note: I saw the question: [What is the C++11 equivalent to boost::date_time::not_a_date_time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25880503/what-is-the-c11-equivalent-to-boostdate-timenot-a-date-time). There is no rectification. So I want to be more specific about my problem to get an answer.

I have a boost::system_time, that will be cleared occasionally by assigning boost::date_time::not_a_date_time.

```
class Data
{
    boost::system_time dateTime;
    void clear(void)
    {
        dateTime = boost::date_time::not_a_date_time;
    }
    const boost::system_time &getDateTime() const
    {
        return dateTime;
    }
};
void main()
{
    Data obj;
    // Some processing of Data obj
    if ( obj.getDateTime() >= now )
    {
        // inform some other module
    }
}
```

Now, is there anything in STL, that can be assigned some value (let's say now()) and cleared to be an invalid value?

Tried creating time_point with empty constructor. It is pointing to Epoch time. 
I see in some odd scenarios, the time_point will have null value. Is there any way to achieve it (If it is safe)

Comment: Last time I checked the standard library has no datetime types at all. Can you make it clear what you are talking about?

Comment: The code I mentioned is a part of my application. It is using boost::date_time object. I want to replace boost features with STL. As an initializer, they're clearing the date_time object by assigning not_a_date_time. I can replace this date_time with system_clock or time_point. But there is nothing in STL to clear system-clock or time_point.

Comment: The STL has no concepts of dates or times, so it isn't clear what you're after.

Comment: That's a big statement... std::chrono has almost all solutions to the dates and times. I just couldn't find the exact replacement of not_a_date_time. I can simply replace it with high_resolution_clock::time_point

Comment: @Neo Which statement? If you mean mine, the STL had no chrono functionality.

Comment: The cited SO question is answered perfectly. There is no search-and-replace solution. read that answer and try to understand it.

Comment: @juanchopanza, sorry if I'm being rude. STL has chrono header file. In my application, I'm using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point. I believe that this can serve my purpose of dealing with dates and times (with the combination of std::chrono::duration)

Comment: @stefan, I do understand that there is no search and replace solution for this problem. I'm not expecting one as well. But I just thought if there is a way of representing invalid time in STL (like time_t value with some invalid value or time_point being invalid value)

Comment: @Neo No, the STL doesn't have that unless it has been recently back-ported. `std::chrono` is C++ standard library since C++11. It isn't even based on any STL code. And you're not being rude by the way!