# std::chrono::time_point invalid value

Tags: c++

```
boost/std :: chrono::time_point my_time_point( /* invalid value */ );
```

I am in need to store an invalid/nonsensical/sentinel value. How can I possibly do that?

Comment: Look into boost::optional or std::optional: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html

Comment: You sure it would help? I need `my_time_point` to store an invalid value

Comment: The point of 'optional' is providing an "extra value" in the domain of your choice that represents a "null"/"invalid" state

Comment: It seems to me now, that there is no such thing as invalid value in std/boost::chrono ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25880503/what-is-the-c11-equivalent-to-boostdate-timenot-a-date-time ). Anyhow, thanks for your efforts

Comment: @user3600124: What Vittorio is saying is that if you wrap it with a `boost::optional` it *will* have a a null/invalid value that you can check for.

Comment: Why all the down votes?  Seems like a reasonable question to me.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) *(or  [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) if you have C++17 support)* to represent an invalid state of `chrono::time_point`:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

int main()
{
    using my_clock = std::chrono::system_clock;
    using my_time_point = std::chrono::time_point<my_clock>;

    boost::optional<my_time_point> maybe_time_point;

    // Set to invalid value:
    maybe_time_point = boost::none;

    // If 'maybe_time_point' is valid...
    if(maybe_time_point) 
    { 
        auto inner_value = *maybe_time_point;
        /* ... */
    }
    else { /* ... */ }
}
```

[*(You can run it **on wandbox**.*)](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/e6adybRhbS7cSYj1)

Comment: Upvoted, but nitpick:  The OP asked about `std::chrono::time_point`, not `boost::chrono::time_point`. :-)

Comment: @HowardHinnant: fixed!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same requirement and turns out there is an elegant solution. If you are OK to set TimePoint to a unreasonably large value into the future {Fri Apr 11 23:47:16 **2262**} then it should be simple to do this.

```
using Clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
using TimePoint = std::chrono::time_point<Clock>;
constexpr TimePoint invalidTime_k = TimePoint::max();

TimePoint my_time_point = invalidTime_k;
```

Warning: This post will lead to a Y2262 problem. But by then we should have better types in the standard.

Comment: `Warning: This post will lead to a Y2262 problem. But by then we should have better types in the standard.`  - don't bet on it :)

Comment: Why not use timepoint::min instead of timepoint::max? Same effect but no risk of a YXXXX bug

Comment: Year 2262 is gonna be none of my business